# Figure location in the bottom of the document

Tags: floats, bibliographies, page-breaking

In my paper the last page should contain reference only, but my figures keep popping in the last page.
How can I force them not to appear in the last page / force the last page to consist of reference only?

Comment: For a very discussion of how LaTeX positions floats, see the answers to the posting [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001). In general, do you *want* the floats to show up on the second-to-last page, or do you want to them to show up closer to where they're created?

Comment: are you using the an option such as `\begin{figure}[h]` ? (If you are, don't)

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Issue a `\cleardoublepage` just before your reference section. `\clearpage` may be enough, depending on your document layout/class.